# How to get the Euler angles of a body from its MotionState in Bullet Physics?

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

The [official hello world](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/2.83/examples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cpp#L134) prints the x, y and z positions of a falling object, which are extracted via `body->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(trans)`.

But how would I get the three Euler angles that represent the rotation?

I am able to get the quaternion that represents the rotation with [`btTransform::getRotation()`](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtTransform.html#a0000b60c68876844b43fc298507b7520), but is there a convenient way to convert them to Euler angles?

I could re-implement the conversion formula as mentioned at [Rotating Objects Using Quaternions](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131686/rotating_objects_using_quaternions.php), but I'd expect Bullet to have a built-in method for it.

I have seen [How to get the Euler rotation of a rigid body between 0 to 360 in Bullet Physics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869130/bullet-physics-rotation-of-rigid-body) but it does not use MotionState, which I've read is the preferred method (but I don't understand why yet).

Cross posted at: http://www.bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11142